# What's the significance of worshiping Shiva in the month of Shravan?

Tags: shiva, rituals, worship, puja

We all know about worshipping Shiva in the month of *Shravana* (श्रावण), especially on every Monday of that month i.e *Shravana Somavara*.
What's the significance of worshipping Shiva in *Shravana*? In other words, How is the *Shravana* month significant or special for Shiva?
Is it described or mentioned in any scripture like Purana?

Answer (score 6):

Actually a great question to answer and think about... Not much facts are known about this. But still the month is holy according to puranas and fortunately even I was born in this month only.:)

Few facts (or stories) that I know:

***During the Shravan/Sawan month, it is believed that worshiping Lord Shiva is 108 times more powerful than worshipping during normal days.***

According to the legend, **Devi Sati sacrificed her in this month** and before dying she swore that she would marry Shiva in every succeeding life.Devi Sati was born as Parvati in her next life. She fasted during the month of sawan due to which Lord Shiva was impressed and they used to meet up on Monday. since then,the Monday and fasting has a great importance in the month of Sawan.

As described [here](http://hindupad.com/significance-and-greatness-of-sawan-month-importance-of-shravan-maas/) - In Vedas, *Shravan* month is described as **Nabhas**. Shravan purnima coincides with the Nakshatra (Shravan) of *Lord Vishnu*. Hence the name. This is also one of the main reasons why this month is important and auspicious.

According to hindu mythology, **The story of Amarnath pilgrimage** where Lord Shiva tells a story of immortality to Goddess Parvati is the most important one. *When Lord Shiva began the story of immortality, Goddess Parvati fell asleep. However, a parrot present there at that moment heard the story. After listening to the entire story, the parrot became immortal. The parrot escaped the wrath of Lord Shiva and was born as the Shukdev later*.

Later in Naimisharanya, Shukdev told - **In the month of Sawan only Shiva consumed poison**. The Samudra Manthan is a very important episode as per the Puranas. The churning of the milky ocean, i.e. Samudra Manthan in search of the amrit, took place during the month of Shravan. During the churning, 14 different rubies emerged from the ocean. Thirteen rubies were divided among the devas and the asuras, however, Halahal, the 14th ruby remained untouched as it was the deadliest poison which could destroy the whole universe and every living being. Lord Shiva drank the Halahal and stored the poison in his throat. Due to the impact of the poison, his throat turned blue and he came to be called Neelkantha. Since this was the time when Shiva saved everyone from dying, he is worshipped with priority in the month of Sawan only.

Such was the impact of the poison that Lord Shiva wore a crescent moon on his head and all the devas started offering water from the holy river of Ganges to lord Shiva to reduce the effects of the poison. Both these events took place in the Shravan Maas and therefore, it is considered very auspicious to offer holy Ganga water to Lord Shiva in this month.

According to a religious belief, son of Markandu Rishi, Markanday too for long life worshipped Lord Shiva in the month of Sawan only.

Comment: Sati sacrificed *herself*

Comment: Ya but actually I was not confirmed about it so I dint mention.:)

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uttarayana

> The Surya Siddhanta defines Uttarāyaṇa or Uttarayan as the period
>   between the Makara Sankranti (which currently occurs around January
>   14) and Karka Sankranti (which currently occurs around July 16).[1][2]
>   The term Uttarayana is derived from two different Sanskrit words
>   "uttara" (North) and "ayana" (movement) thus indicating a semantic of
>   the northward movement of the Earth on the celestial sphere.
>
> According to Hindu tradition the six months of Uttarayana are a single
>   day of the Gods; the six months of Dakshinayana are a single night of
>   the Gods. Thus a year of twelve months is single Nychthemeron of the
>   Gods.

**Shravan is linked to Lord Shiva in following 2main ways:**

1) He is Lord of Snakes

> Nag Panchami Nag Panchami is also celebrated in many parts of India on
>   the fifth day after Amavasya of Shraavana month. The snake god Nāga is
>   worshiped. The last day of the Shraavana is celebrated as Pola, where
>   the bull is worshiped by farmers from Maharashtra
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naga_Panchami
>
> In the Mahabharata epic story, Astika, the Brahmin son of Jaratkarus,
>   who stopped the Sarpa Satra of Janamejaya, ruler of the Kuru empire
>   which lasted for 12 years is well documented. This yagna was performed
>   by Janamejaya to decimate the race of all snakes, to avenge for the
>   death of his father Parikshita due to snake bite of Takshaka, the king
>   of snakes. The day that the yagna (fire sacrifice) was stopped, due to
>   the intervention of the Astika, was on the Shukla Paksha Panchami day
>   in the month of Shravana when Takshaka, the king of snakes and his
>   remaining race at that time were saved from decimation by the Sarpa
>   Satra yagna. Since that day, the festival is observed as Naga
>   Panchami.

2) He opened his eyes in Ashadha Purnima/ Guru Purnima, month before the Shraavan Purnima and 12 months are actually 6 ritus(so Ashadha and Shraavan are of same ritu(season) i.e Varsha ritu
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guru_Purnima

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_calendar

**Mithuna   Ashadha June–July   Varṣā   monsoon**

**Karkaṭa   Shraavana   July-Aug    Varsa   monsoon**

> Traditionally the festival is celebrated by Buddhists in honor of the
>   lord Buddha who gave His first sermon on this day at Varanasi(city of
>   Shiva) , Uttar Pradesh, India. In the yogic tradition, the day is
>   celebrated as the occasion when **Shiva became the first Guru, as he
>   began the transmission of yoga to the Saptarishis**

https://isha.sadhguru.org/in/en/wisdom/article/the-first-yogi

> On a full moon day, after eighty-four years of sadhana, when the
>   solstice had shifted from the summer solstice to the winter solstice –
>   which in this tradition is known as Dakshinayana – the Adiyogi Shiva looked
>   at these seven people and saw that they had become shining receptacles
>   of knowing. They were absolutely ripe to receive. He could not ignore
>   them anymore. They grabbed his attention.
>
> He watched them closely for the next few days and when the next full
>   moon rose, he decided to become a Guru. The Adiyogi transformed
>   himself into the Adi Guru; the first Guru was born on that day which
>   is today known as Guru Purnima.
>
> After many years, when the transmission was complete, it produced
>   seven fully enlightened beings – the seven celebrated sages who are
>   today known as the Saptarishis, and are worshipped and admired in
>   Indian culture. Shiva put different aspects of yoga into each of these
>   seven people, and these aspects became the seven basic forms of yoga.
>   Even today, yoga has maintained these seven distinct forms.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! It looks like you're a new user. Take a [tour] and visit [help]. Wikipedia and blogs are not reliable source to cite.

Comment: the first answer is without any references, follow the links at bottom of wikipedia pages they go right into source

Comment: we arenot doing a phd of hinduism

Comment: I am not new, i am Ravi :/

Comment: You may directly quote that original source.

Comment: ohk. I didn't get; have you changed the name recently to Father?

Comment: ohk! you meant user16546?

Comment: yes, thats me, someone made my points 0  and deleted my account