# What are the legends associated with Kānwar Yātrā (कांवड़ यात्रा) and which scriptures mention them?

Tags: shiva, rituals, practice

**Kānwar Yātrā (कांवड़ यात्रा)**: In the month of Shravan, Millions devotees (from North India) walk for hundreds of miles to collect holy water from the Ganga to offer in their local Shiva temples. This is known as Kānwar Yātrā (कांवड़ यात्रा).

What are the legends associated with Kānwar Yātrā (कांवड़ यात्रा) and which scriptures mention them?

---

Update:

This question might be related with [What's the significance of worshiping Shiva in the month of Shravan?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20264/whats-the-significance-of-worshiping-shiva-in-the-month-of-shravan) but it's not duplicate. I am concerned with Kānwar Yātrā (कांवड़ यात्रा) where water is brought in a different manner (on shoulder with the help of a bamboo stick with Ganga-jala pots on both ends).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the significance of worshiping Shiva in the month of Shravan?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20264/whats-the-significance-of-worshiping-shiva-in-the-month-of-shravan)

Comment: It's actually a duplicate because in various regions of India it is a well known tradition to worship Lord Shiva in that particular month. What is called Kanwar Yatra in northern India is known as Tarakeswar Yatra in Bengal. There too millions of devotees carry Ganges water on their shoulders and complete the journey barefooted. So,it boils down to the same Q. Only temples names are different. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarakeswar