# What is the scenario when Shiva consumed halahal (poison) as per Shiva purana

Tags: shiva, worship, shiva-purana, samudra-manthan

Please describe briefly about the incident, when Shiva had consumed poison in the request of gods & to keep low the body temperature of Lord Shiva, moon was placed on his head & how gods have offered water and belpatra as per Shiva purana.

Comment: Probably a duplicate: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20264/whats-the-significance-of-worshiping-shiva-in-the-month-of-shravan

Comment: If you decide to remove the Shravan month connection from the Q then it won't be a dupe though

Comment: To keep a low temperature?